# Do we create index for the field which is used in query during sorting purpose?

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB for our Application with java as shown below .
I am making a below query as shown below :

```
public Set<String> findDuplicateEquities() {
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject sort = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("symbol", "SUNG");
sort.put("price", "1");
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query).sort(sort);
```

Do i need to create the **index** for the **price** field also , as i am usng it for the **sort** purpse ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how many documents are returned by `find({symbol:"SUNG"})`. When only a handfull of entries are returned which then need to be sorted, I wouldn't bother. But when this query returns several hundred documents or more, creating a compound index including price could help, because then the entries can already be retrieved in a sorted order from the index and don't have to be sorted afterwards.

Note that an index which is supposed to speed up a `find( ... ).sort( ... )` needs to be a compound index which starts with all fields which are matched exactly by the find-query followed immediately by the fields you are sorting by in the correct order and direction. For more information read [the documentation about compound indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/).